# Purchased domain, purchased hosting, how do I link the two?

Tags: web, dns, web-hosting

Pretty much what the title says. I purchased a .com domain for my first personal site ever from gandi.net and I purchased shared hosting space from lithium hosting.

I haven't found any specific instructions for how to make the domain name use the hosting space I purchased, so if you guys could advise me on that, it'd be fantastic!

Thanks!

Comment: +1, I'm not sure for that anonymous -1. Question seems clear, though a bit offtopic for SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically you log in to the place you registered the Domain (gandi.net) and there should be a place to configure the Name servers for that domain. Lithium hosting should have info somewhere on what their nameservers are, so find that and put them on gandi.net. There maybe some additional setup you have to do on the Lithium side as well (like telling them what domain name you are hosting on their services).

Answer (score 1):

You will have to point domain NameServers to your hosting eg NS1.YOURHOSTING.COM NS2.YOURHOSTING.COM, that is in your case pretty much it.

NS1.LITHIUMHOSTING.COM -> 184.82.230.74
NS2.LITHIUMHOSTING.COM -> 184.82.44.168

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the people from whom you purchased the domain that they should point it to your webspace which is identified by an other name or an ip address. Look for something like "CNAME Resource Record" or "A Resource Record".

If you cannot find a menu on the site to do this just contact the support.